# How generate documentation with maven-swagger-codegen-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I have configured swagger-codegen-plugin like that

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/model.json</inputSpec>
                    <language>java</language>
                    <configOptions>
                        <sourceFolder>src/gen/java/main</sourceFolder>
                    </configOptions>
                    <modelPackage>com.mypackage</modelPackage>
                    <environmentVariables>
                        <models></models>
                        <supportingFiles>false</supportingFiles>
                    </environmentVariables>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Everything works, but when I change language to `<language>html</language>` nothing was generate.

So how to generation staitc html documentation?

Comment: Can you check the `target/generated-sources/swagger/` folder? There should be a `index.html` file. I'm not sure whether it takes the `sourceFolder`

Comment: There are some files, but not html files at all!!!

Comment: Maybe the maven log would be helpful. It is really hard to figure it out. Your config looks good

Answer (score 1):

At present, you are specifying the language as `<language>java</language>` to generate html this should either be`<language>html</language>` or`<language>html2</language>` as this specifies the output language generator for swagger-codegen.

There are 2 different html generators so you will need to decide your preferred flavour.